# Android animacion para ImageView

Tags: android

Resulta que en mi activity splash, tengo una imagen, que cuando se abre la app, se muestra como animacion, y se traslada desde abajo hacia arriba pero despues vuelve al centro de la pantalla. no logro que la imagen se quede arriba de la pantalla. Cual es la propiedad o que tengo que modificar?

este es mi translate

```xml
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="0%"
android:toXDelta="0%"
android:fromYDelta="200%"
android:toYDelta="-90%"
android:duration="5000"
android:zAdjustment="top"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega la propiedad  **[fillAfter](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:fillAfter)** en true :

```
android:fillAfter="true"
```

> **[fillAfter](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:fillAfter)** define si se debe aplicar la transformación de animación después de la animación completa o no. Si se establece en
>   false el elemento cambia a su estado anterior después de la animación.

Comment: gracias.. Problema resuelto